# Enum Extension Method is not showing

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to add new/extension method for Enum but the extension method is not showing on intellisense method list. Please help here's my code.

**Extension:**

```
public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static string GetDescriptionAttr(this Enum value,string key)
        {
            var type = value.GetType();
            var memInfo = type.GetMember(key);
            var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
                false);
            var description = ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
            return description;
        }
    }
```

**Trying to call the result from other class (both caller and extension are in the same project)**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extension methods can be applied on *instances* only

```
public static class EnumExtensions {
  // This extension method requires "value" argument
  // that should be an instance of Enum class 
  public static string GetDescriptionAttr(this Enum value, string key) {
    ...
  }
}

...

public enum MyEnum {
  One, 
  Two,
  Three
}

Enum myEnum = MyEnum.One;

// You can call extension method on instance (myEnum) only
myEnum.GetDescriptionAttr("One");
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks also for the explanation. This has solved my confusion.

Comment: The fact that the Extension method is static, makes you think you can call it statically.

Answer (score 3):

You should use extension method for an instance of your enum.
I have this code and it works properly:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    var attributes = 
        (DescriptionAttribute[])value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
}
```

And using of this method shows here:

```
MyEnum myE = MyEnum.OneOfItemsOfEnum;
string description = myE.GetDescription();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this variant

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Web.Extensions
{
    public static class EnumExtension
    {
        public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
        {
            var displayName = enumValue.GetType()?
                .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                .FirstOrDefault()?
                .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?
                .Name;

            return displayName ?? enumValue.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

enum definition

```
public enum SomeEnum
    {
        One= 1,
        [Display(Name = "Second")]
        Two= 2,
        Three= 3
    }
```

and in view (extension called directly).

```
display name from enum
@Web.Extensions.EnumExtension.GetDisplayName(Domain.Enums.SomeEnum.Two)
show display name from enum id
@Web.Extensions.EnumExtension.GetDisplayName((Domain.Enums.SomeEnum)2)
show display name from enum id without display attribute
@Web.Extensions.EnumExtension.GetDisplayName((Domain.Enums.SomeEnum)3)
```

outputs

```
Second
Second
Three
```

or more simply

```
@using Web.Extensions
@using Domain.Enums

@SomeEnum.Two.GetDisplayName()
@(((SomeEnum)2).GetDisplayName())
```